# Canvas animation in line graph

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-sortable

How we can draw and animate (continuously run ) basic line chart in jquery.

http://prntscr.com/kifamc

Can you please help me.

I have tried this below code but does not work as per image. This code give line graph. I do not need x and y axis. only show cured line continuously show with their points

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width:100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var dps = [];
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      exportEnabled: true,
      title: { text: "Dynamic Spline Chart" },
      axisY: { includeZero: false },
      data: [{ type: "spline", markerSize: 0, dataPoints: dps }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100;
    var updateInterval = 1000;
    var dataLength = 50; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function(count) {
      count = count || 1;
      // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.
      for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        yVal = yVal + Math.round(5 + Math.random() * (-5 - 5));
        dps.push({ x: xVal, y: yVal });
        xVal++;
      }
      if (dps.length > dataLength) {
        dps.shift();
      }
      chart.render();
    };

    updateChart(dataLength);
    setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself to create this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of options for the axis, take a peek at the documentation:
https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/

You can hide the axis labels using `labelFormatter`, below is an example based on your code:

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 180px; width:100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var dps = [];
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    exportEnabled: true,
    axisX: {includeZero: false, lineThickness: 0, labelFormatter: function(){return ""}},
    axisY: {includeZero: false, lineThickness: 0, labelFormatter: function(){return ""}},
    data: [{ type: "spline", markerSize: 0, dataPoints: dps }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100;
    var dataLength = 50; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function(count) {
    count = count || 1;
    // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        yVal = yVal + Math.round(5 + Math.random() * (-5 - 5));
        dps.push({ x: xVal++, y: yVal });
    }
    if (dps.length > dataLength) {
        dps.shift();
    }
    chart.render();
    };

    updateChart(dataLength);
    setInterval(updateChart, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need more soomth effect like this site  https://www.healthcarelogic.com/  .  & need to remvoe  menu icon as well . can you please help me

Comment: HelderSepu : gap in between two curd also need to increase.how can we achive ?

Comment: HelderSepu : you get my comment ?

Comment: @Abhijit sorry but I'm no expert on CanvasJS, this was a push on what I think is the correct direction, you need to read the documentation and experiment with the options.